# StringTemplate can not render attribute of LINQ to SQL class

Tags: asp.net, linq, stringtemplate

i use GUI tool of vs2008 to generate some LINQ to SQL class, my problem is StringTemplate can not reach attributes of those model

```
$persons:{
<li>$it.name$</li>
}$
```

it printed:

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

**name** is public property of **Person** model. If i create a person class by myself, and the same attributes, StringTemplate can get it.

Answer (score 1):

The designer produces a normal class with respect to the compiler, the code is simply autogenerated.  I suspect that you have some other issue going on -- perhaps you haven't included the correct references/namespaces or you have a namespace conflict and it's picking the wrong class.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct solution, but I am having the same trouble, and using `$it._name$` works for me. This is accessing the private backing field though, so is not a good idea. Still, it means that StringTemplate can find that field, but not the `name` property to go with it. Odd.

Edit:

Got it. StringTemplate assumes that properties start with an uppercase letter. so if your property was called `Name` it would work. You could rename your properties or fix the offending bit of code in StringTemplate's source at
`ASTExpr.cs:RawGetObjectProperty` around the call to `GetPropertyValueByName` (it uses `methodSuffix`, not `propertyName`).